Writing a bash script to wait for a process on a remote machine to finish
I'm writing a script to automate some tasks, one of the steps is to wait for a process started on a remote machine to finish execution.
My idea is to show a spinner while the process keeps executing, with inspiration from this question.
The relevant part of the code is this -
spinner_wait_remote() {

    local pid=$1
    local msg=${2-Process $pid still running}
    local spin='-\|/'
    local i=0
    while ssh "$remote_machine" "kill -0 $pid" 2>/dev/null
    do
        local i=$(( (i+1) %4 ))
        printf "\r${spin:$i:1} $msg"
        sleep .1
    done
    printf "\n\e[A\e[K"
}

The problem is, it never enters the while loop, although the $pid exists in the remote machine.
I have a similar method that waits for commands launched in the local machine and it works fine. The only difference is the ssh command in the while condition.
I also tried running the entire while loop on the remote machine, but it still doesn't seem to enter the while loop.
spinner_wait_remote() {

    pid=$1
    msg=${2-Process $pid still running}
    ssh "$remote_server" "
        spin='-\|/'
        i=0
        while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null
        do
            i=$(( (i+1) %4 ))
            printf \"\r${spin:$i:1} $msg\"
            sleep .1
        done
        printf \"\n\e[A\e[K\"
    "
}


if it worked you'd be launching a new ssh connection ten times each second. seems a very resource-intensive way to draw a few characters

what is output when you remove 2>/dev/null ?

perhaps a redesign/rethink .... 1) spawn a background process to start the spinner (making note of the backgrounded process's pid), 2) run the remote/ssh call (in the foreground) and then 3) when the remote/ssh call completes you kill of the backgrounded spinner process

It's a lot less problem-prone to define the code you want to run remotely in a function and let bash serialize that function for you. spinner() { ...; }, then ssh remote_server "$(declare -f spinner); spinner ${pid@Q}" (assuming bash 5.x for the @Q). No extra escapes/backslashes/etc needed that way; you just write the code the exact same way you'd run it locally.

Once you've got the issues described in the linked duplicate worked out, if you're still having problems, consider using set -x; at the front of your remote command to get more logging so you can narrow down a specific problem and ask a question that's narrowly focused on that problem.

Thank you for all the suggestions. To answer @jhnc, yes it's overkill to launch ssh just to show a few moving characters, but I was trying it out to see if it was possible to do so. (Still learning).

Serializing the function is exactly what I was looking for and it did the job, with just a single ssh connection. Thanks @CharlesDuffy for pointing it out!!
